# Is answer of limit an exact value?

Tags: limits, functions

Suppose I am finding $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 2} \frac{x^2 - 4}{x - 2}$$

The answer comes out to be 4. Is '4' exact value or approaching value?

Also we have $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$$ I know that this value of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is slightly less than $1$ in neighborhood of $x=0$ so what if we are asked $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\bigg\lfloor  \frac{\sin x}{x} \bigg\rfloor $$
Will answer be $1$ or $0$ and are $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\bigg\lfloor  \frac{\sin x}{x} \bigg\rfloor $$ and 
$$\bigg\lfloor  \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} \bigg\rfloor$$
same or different?

Comment: '4' is an exact value of the first limit. The second limit is equal to $0$ and the third is equal to $1$.

Comment: $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is not a continuous function at $x=0$, so the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}$ cannot go into the $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ in general.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Why is $4$ exact value? Value $x$ is not exactly $2$

Comment: @Mathematics See please  my post.

Comment: The limit is the value that is being approached, not the thing which approaches. Think of the number 4 as sitting on the number line and waiting for the expression $(x^2-4)/(x-2)$ to arrive (which it never really does, but it gets arbitrarily close). That number (exactly) is then the limit. It's like if you're saying “my destination is Spain”. The destination (Spain) isn't moving, *you* are moving. But the destination is still (exactly) Spain.

Comment: @HansLundmark That is the explanation I was looking for. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow2}\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow2}\frac{(x-2)(x+2)}{x-2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow2}(x+2)=4.$$
If $x\rightarrow2$ then $x\neq2$ by the definition of the limit.

Comment: As $x$ is not exactly 2, then why are we saying that answer is exactly $4$?

Comment: @Mathematics: It's called a limit, not the value of the expression. Read the definition of limit

Comment: @Mathematics You asked about $\lim$. There is a definition of limit. Use this definition. We can say that $x$ is not exactly $2$ and the limit is equal to exactly $4$. This statement seems very strange, but we can say that it's true.

Answer (score 1):

The limit
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\bigg\lfloor  \frac{\sin x}{x} \bigg\rfloor = 0 $$

because $\ \bigg\lfloor  \displaystyle{\frac{\sin x}{x}} \bigg\rfloor=0\ $ near 0 since the function $\displaystyle{\frac{\sin x}{x}}$ is bounded :

$$ 0 \leq \frac{\sin x}{x} < 1,\ \ \forall x\in[-\pi,\pi] $$

and this implies that:

$$ \ \bigg\lfloor  \displaystyle{\frac{\sin x}{x}} \bigg\rfloor=0,\ \ \forall x\neq 0\ \ \text{and}\ \ x\in[-\pi,\pi]  $$

and you know that $\ \underset{x\to 0}{\lim}{\displaystyle{\frac{\sin x}{x}}}=1$ and this implies that

$$ \bigg\lfloor\underset{x\to 0}{\lim}{\displaystyle{\frac{\sin x}{x}}}\bigg\rfloor = 1  $$